# Truthiness of integer Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I just happened to try this out and I'm very confused why Pandas Series consider **even** numbers *true* and **odd** numbers *false*.

```py
data = {
  "calories": [420,560, 235, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 345, 123, 40, 45]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(tdata)


print(df[df['calories'] & True])
```

returns

```
   calories  duration
2       235       123
```

which doesn't seem right. I thought all non-zero values were "truthy" in Python?

Comment: & bitwise operation, 235 odd, others are even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last bit of odd numbers is 1, the last bit of even numbers is 0. You’re doing a bit-wise AND of a number with 0b00…001 (`True`), which will only return 1 when the number was odd, and 0 otherwise.

If you want to *compare* with `True`, you need to use a comparison operator (e.g. `==`).

Comment: `50 and True`, `422 and True` and `423 and True` will all return `True` also. <number> `& True` returns `1` for odd numbers and `0` for even.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! I was actually trying to test for existence (e.g. `df['calories'].isna()`) originally and made an error and discovered this (seemingly) weird behavior.